# Freeing up _bstr_t which is created from char*

Tags: c++, windows, memory, memory-management, bstr

I have char* array and I am dynamically allocating memory for it.

```
char *strData = new char[length+1];
```

This char* I am passing to _bstr_t as below,

```
_bstr_t bstrData = strData;
```

How to free up the memory  allocated for the char* through bstrData ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_bstr_t` manages its own internal buffer (created by [SysAllocString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms891285.aspx)). So once you create the `_bstr_t`, it's safe to delete the char array you've allocated. `bstrData` will still be absolutely useful.